Choose what build tool to import from in IDEA
I have a project that has a dual-build system: Gradle, and Bazel (for a subset of modules). After I installed the IntelliJ Bazel plugin the project is automatically imported via Bazel and misses most sub projects. I'd like to force IDEA to import the project via Gradle, but I don't even see the Gradle Tool window anymore. This happens even if the project was already "imported" once via Gradle -- all is lost on open when the Bazel plugin is enabled.
The only way to make it work again is to disable the Bazel plugin. Is there a way to choose what build system to use when the project is open?

I don't think IDEA has an option to choose the Build System, but once your Project is opened with Bazel you can try and right-click the root build.gradle(.kts) and select "Link Gradle Project".

No file even shows up, so I can't see the build.gradle.kts file

Actually, after some fiddling I could make it show all files, but the right-click menu doesn't have the "Link Gradle Project" item.

I can find "Link Gradle Project" in the global search as "disabled action"..

Any chance you can share the Project for further investigation?
